Let $(b_n)$ defined by $b_n = 2^n\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n\rvert$ be a converging sequence. Prove that $(a_n)$ converge.
Let $(b_n)$ defined by $b_n = 2^n\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n\rvert$ be a converging sequence. Prove that $(a_n)$ converge.
This is where I got it. Let $\epsilon > 0$, and since $(b_n)$ converges, there is $M>0$ such that for all $n \in N$, $\lvert b_n\rvert <M$.
Hence, $2^n\lvert a_{n+1} - a_n\rvert <M$
$\lvert a_{n+1} -a_n\rvert<\frac M {2^n}$.
Is it enough for me to now choose $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $2^N > \frac m\epsilon$. or do i need to really set $N$ some other way?

Actually $M/2^n < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. By Archimedean property, you can able to say that $2^N > m/\epsilon$

Let's say we agreed on how to choose $N$ and we know that $\lvert a_{n+1} -a_n\rvert \to 0$. But what if someone asks how convergence follows from this?

In general if $\sum_n |a_{n + 1} - a_n|$ converges then so does $(a_n)$. Note that $|a_{n + 1} - a_n| \to 0$ alone (a strictly weaker condition) does not imply that $(a_n)$ converges though.

You have shown $\lvert a_{n+1} -a_n\rvert<\dfrac M {2^n}$. A standard argument(see below) now shows the sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, hence convergent.
If $m>n$ then
\begin{align*}
   |a_n-a_m|
& \leq |a_n-a_{n+1}|+|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|+\cdots+|a_{m-1}-a_m|\\ 
& \leq M\left(\tfrac{1}{2^n}+\tfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\cdots+\tfrac{1}{2^{m-1}}\right)\\
& \leq \tfrac{M}{2^{n-1}}
\end{align*}

You have the converging:
$$b_n=2^n|a_n-a_{n+1}|$$
I.e. as you mention : $b_n<M$
i.e. $$|a_n-a_{n+1}|<M/2^{n}$$
which means the series $|a_n-a_{n+1}|$ is absolutely convergent thus convergent, thus $a_n$ converge.
